# Tabulator: If Row 1 cell 1 > 10 and Row 1 cell 2 > 100, how to send "GO" to Row1 cell 3

Tags: tabulator

I have a Tabulator grid with 6 columns, 2000 rows, fed by streaming data.
If any row has cell1 and cell2 that meet minimum (example: Row1 cell1 value > 10 and Row1 cell2 value > 100), I need to put "GO" in Row1 cell3 and send "GO" to document.getElementById("GOBox").innerHTML = "GO".
Seems simple, but I have tried many code combination, nothing works so far. Thanks,

```
    {title:"Go", field:"go",  hozAlign:"center", width: "5pt",
        mutator: function(value, data) {
        let oval = data.cell1;
        let bval = data.cell2;
        if (oval >10
         && bval > 100){
        return "GO";

        //document.getElementById("GOBox").innerHTML = "GO"}
         }},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example should work unless there is an issue elsewhere.  Are you getting an error?

Here is a basic working example:

```js
const tableData = [
  { oval: 18, bval: 100 },
  { oval: 11, bval: 120 },
  { oval: 2, bval: 112 },
  { oval: 58, bval: 2 },
  { oval: 80, bval: 250 }
]

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: tableData,
  columns: [
    { title: 'oVal', field: 'oval' },
    { title: 'bVal', field: 'bval' },
    {
      title: 'Go',
      field: 'go',
      mutator: (value, data) => {
        if (data.oval > 10 && data.bval > 100) {
          document.getElementById("GOBox").innerHTML = "GO"
          return 'GO'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id='table'></div>
<br>
<div id='GOBox'></div>
```